# Core Data divide two values

Tags: cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, accessor

In my project, which is written entirely with Core Data and bindings, I have two text fields which contain float values. I want to make a third text field that is the first field divided by the second. What is the best way to go about this using Core Data? Should I make a custom accessor for the third field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a method -thirdValue in your NSManagedObject subclass that does the calculation:

```
- (CGFloat)thirdValue
{
  return value1 / value2; // should probably do a value2 != 0 check
}
```

and then +keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey for the class:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{   
    NSSet *superSet = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"thirdValue"])
        return [[NSMutableSet setWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil] unionSet:superSet];

    return superSet;
}
```

this sets up thirdValue to be dependent on value1 and value2.  Whenever value1 or value2 change, there will also be a KVO notification for thirdValue.  So if you have a field that binds to it, the field will display the new calculated value.  It's a a handy trick when you need to display a key who's value is dependent on other keys.

Comment: It’s good practice to call `super` and either merge the returned set with the one that’s being created or, in case the key is not thirdValue, to return the set returned by `super`.

Comment: True, answer edited with this addition.  The original was a quick and dirty answer written in site's editor.